# Failed to use Package Forms9Patch in Xamarin iOS project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I trying to show text with html format in xamarin forms using the nuget package "Forms9Patch",it worked succefully in Xamarin.Forms Android Project but When I tried it on Xamarin.Forms iOS project I Got this error :

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Can't resolve the reference 'CoreGraphics.CGRect UIKit.NSLayoutManager::GetLineFragmentRect(System.nuint,Foundation.NSRange&)', referenced from the method 'System.UInt32 Forms9Patch.iOS.UITextViewExtensions::NumberOfLines(UIKit.UITextView)' in 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'."

Can Any one Explain it to me and how to solve it ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to make the Forms9Patch package work in a blank Xamarin iOS Project? Could you also share a detailed StackTrace of your error? Is the error compile time or run time?

Comment: I am the author of that package. I am currently on my phone but I will be able to take a closer look later today.

Comment: @Saamer It's à compile error ,the output box show me the error posted !!I didn't even understand what does it mean :(

Comment: @baskren I also tried to run your demo posted on github I got also the same error :( any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: @AichaMaghrebi which demo on Github did you try to run. I can try to run it on my machine. Are you using the latest Visual Studio? And are you using a Mac machine?

Comment: @Saamer I tried the demo puted by baskren on github because he is he author of the package,this is the demo (https://github.com/baskren/Forms9PatchDemo) it show me also the same error :( Iam using 15.9.4 the version of VS and I am using windows machine the mac machine just for the build (mac mini) :)

Comment: Hey @AichaMaghrebi, I just built that example on my Mac mini (without using a Windows machine). I just had to remove line 286 of PopupsPage.cs (Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical), but apart from that there were no issues. Are you sure that the VS version is the latest on both the Windows and the Mac ?

Comment: @Saamer really thank you for your help :) yes I am sure that VS version is the latest on both Windows and Mac ,really I have no idea how to solve this problem I tried another time but I had also the same issue :(

Comment: OK try to go into the ios project options and change the linker behavior between link all assemblies and dont link assemblies. And you could also try installing the alpha build of Xamarin iOS to see if its reproducible there. Is there a particular reason you have to use that nuget?